# How to extract long and lat from geometry column in GeoPandas?

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, geopandas

I read a shapefile with GeoPandas and I get a nice table with a column `"geometry"`. This column contains `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` or `shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon` object.

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("ashapefile.shp")
```

Now I would like to use this geoDataFrame to make such as a chloropeth plot or something else. Thus I would like to get the (x, y) coordinates, (latitude, longitude) of these polygons.

For example if I do :

```
for boundary in gdf.boundary:
    print(boundary.xy)
```

Thus `boundary` are `shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString` or `MultiLineString`. `boundary.xy` are what I am looking for. But for MultilineString I have to do a loop on all the line.

Is there the way to do that ? Or is there a more simple or straightforward way ?

EDIT :
Issue with `unary_union`:

[image: Issue with unary_union]

Comment: Check out my Shapely and GeoPandas answer: ["Flatten geometry and count coordinates"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/457595/202251)

Answer (score 4):

A polygons shapefile

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file("polys.shp")
gdf.head(2)
```

[image]

Number of polygons

```
gdf.groupby('POLY_NUM_B').count()
        Pb  Zn  geometry
 POLY_NUM_B                  
 24      1   1         1
 25      1   1         1
 26      1   1         1
 27      1   1         1
 28      1   1         1
```

Extraction of the the nodes of the polygons exterior coordinates ([Shapely: polygon](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons))

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
     for pt in list(row['geometry'].exterior.coords): 
        print Point(pt)
POINT (-716632.5126561673 -954202.6388434628)
POINT (-716599.344199169 -954224.8253932064)
POINT (-716538.7964301996 -954240.9772354551)
POINT (-716529.3520701742 -954273.9782994529)
POINT (-716550.9210327187 -954269.8358586552)
POINT (-716600.4004366234 -954260.3328329064)
POINT (-716627.870139441 -954255.056896301)
POINT (-716639.1558135629 -954227.2907514013)
....
```

With MultiPolygons, you need to adapt the script or use Shapely `unary_union` (conversion of a MultiPolygon  to a Polygon) before as in [Geopandas [Shapely] spatial difference: TopologyException: no outgoing dirEdge found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217858/2581)

Creation of a new nodes (Points) GeoDataFrame with the columns of gdf

```
col = gdf.columns.tolist()[0:4]
print col
[u'POLY_NUM_B', u'Pb', u'Zn', 'geometry']
# New GeoDataFrame 
nodes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=col)
# extraction of nodes and attribute values nouveau GeoDataFrame
for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    for pt in list(row['geometry'].exterior.coords): 
        nodes = nodes.append({'POLY_NUM_B': int(row['POLY_NUM_B']), 'Pb':row['Pb'],'Zn':row['Zn'], 'geometry':Point(pt) },ignore_index=True)
nodes.head(5)
```

[image]

Number of nodes of polygons

```
nodes.groupby('POLY_NUM_B').count()
        Pb  Zn  geometry
POLY_NUM_B                  
24.0     9   9         9
25.0    10  10        10
26.0     7   7         7
27.0     6   6         6
28.0     6   6         6
```

Comment: I got an issue with `unary_union`. If I do `unary_union(MULTIPOLYGON)` I obtain a Multipolygon as output.

Comment: I do not understand what happened ? I put a capture of what I did in the first post.