# Counting number of vertices in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

Is there any method to count number of vertices of polygon (or multipolygon etc.) that is in 'geometry' column in datatable, but using GeoPandas?

Example:

Let's say I have polygon

```
POLYGON ((552971.4480249976 155085.9494381994, 552975.0980249938 155093.2494382081, 552980.7980249878 155104.5994382233, 552981.8480249867 155106.6494382256, 552986.8670249796 155118.8284382395, 552993.9820249865 155114.5394382458, 552992.3430249887 155110.6504382399, 552989.1980249948 155100.8494382298, 552983.1480250009 155089.1494382163, 552982.6980250012 155088.5494382135, 552981.3860250067 155080.7984382049, 552971.4480249976 155085.9494381994))
```

After loading shapefile and iterating over lines of data using `iterrows()` method, how to count that this polygons is made from e.g. 41 points, another on 30 etc. Maybe there is some function like `.length` or `.area`?

Comment: check this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218858/49538  "Extraction of the the nodes of the polygons exterior coordinates"

Comment: Check out my Shapely and GeoPandas answer: ["Flatten geometry and count coordinates"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/457595/202251)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`goepandas` uses `shapely` package for geometry. As far as I know, `shapely` has no any function that shows number of vertices like `geometry.vertices` or `len(geometry)` etc. But you can implicitly get the number of vertices of any geometry.

```
import geopandas as gp
df = gp.read_file("shapefile_path")

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # It's better to check if multigeometry
    multi = row.geometry.type.startswith("Multi")

    if multi:
        n = 0
        # iterate over all parts of multigeometry
        for part in row.geometry:
            n += len(part.exterior.coords)
    else: # if single geometry like point, linestring or polygon
        n = len(row.geometry.exterior.coords)

    print(n)
```

If you want to add number of vertices as a column into `df`, try in that way:

```
import geopandas as gp
df = gp.read_file("shapefile_path")

n_vertices=[] ###

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # It's better to check if multigeometry
    multi = row.geometry.type.startswith("Multi")

    if multi:
        n = 0
        # iterate over all parts of multigeometry
        for part in row.geometry:
            n += len(part.exterior.coords)
    else:
        n = len(row.geometry.exterior.coords)
    n_vertices.append(n) ###


df["n_vertices"] = n_vertices ###
df.to_file("new_shapefile_path") ###

# EXAMPLE
#                                           geometry        n_vertices
#  0    POLYGON ((3241688.46003131 4980597.749317063, ...   6
#  1    POLYGON ((3241575.693387136 4980461.03521121, ...   5
```

**EDIT**: This method just counting vertices of exterior ring(s), it doesn't take account of holes (interior ring(s)).

Comment: Thanks! This method is excellent, especially the part when you are checking for multipolygons, cause (i've checked that) it may cause problems. It works quite fast as well. [SOLVED]

Comment: Note that this method fails to account for any interior rings.

Comment: @RutgerH Yes, just counting vertices of exterior ring, not interior's.

Comment: I changed `for part in row.geometry:` to `for part in row.geometry.geoms:` and this worked with geopandas '0.13.0'

Comment: @Cullen.Molitor I didn't test but afaik `geoms` works if geometry type is multipolygon.

Comment: Yes, that is why I changed it to include geoms. Only using geometry it tells me it is not iterable.

Answer (score 7):

I add an example, based on my comment using this [reference](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218858/49538)

I don't know if you have a direct method but you can get what you want using a loop.(I'm using your polygon)

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\fran\Desktop\test.shp")

nodes=[]

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
     for pt in list(row['geometry'].exterior.coords): 
        nodes.append(pt)

len(nodes)
```

And if we check the result with QGIS, we see that it is the same.

[image]

Comment: I did the same (mean checking in QGIS) and it works very accurate.